# Drupal 6 Mimemail with attachment

Tags: drupal, attachment, mime-mail

Can anyone help me with drupal mimemail for attachment i am using below mentioned code to send attachment file on specific email, but somehow its not working, kinldy help me thanks in advance

```
    $body = "test body with attachments";
    $subject = "My test message";

$attachments[]=array(
    'filepath' => file_directory_path().'/document.pdf',
    'filename' => 'wonderful.pdf',
    'filemime' => 'application/pdf',
);

mimemail("xxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxxx2@gmail.com", $subject, $body, NULL, array(), NULL, $attachments,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something very similar. My code is basically:

```
$message['attachments'][] = array(
  'filepath' => $zipfilepath,
  'filename' => 'my-attachment.zip',
  'filemime' => 'application/zip',
);
```

from within my hook_mail module callback. See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_mail/6

Are you sure that you've done the following:

- enabled "mimemail" module;
- checked the option in admin to "Use mime mail for all messages";
- selected "mimemail" as the "E-mail Engine" (at the bottom of the admin page).

Mine is working just fine. I have SMTP module installed as well, and it works with either module selected as the Email Engine.